# Applying a variable number of arguments to one of many functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of functions that may operate over a data structure, where a given function is chosen at a predetermined probability. I do this by assigning a positive integer to each in a list, `itertools.accumulate`-ing the weights, and then `bisect`-ing into the list:

```
func_weights = list(accumulate(weights))
probability = bisect(func_weights, random.random() * func_weights[-1])
```

The issue comes that each of these functions has a slightly different set of parameters/arguments. Some of them require only the data structure, some of them require additional information from the rest of the program. Right now, I build the additional information for every call into a dictionary, and pass into the function as `func[probability](data_struct, **arguments)`, so that I can have each function look like:

```
funcs = [func_1, func_2, func_3, ...]
weights = [1, 2, 3, ...]

func_weights = list(accumulate(weights))
probability = bisect(func_weights, random.random() * func_weights[-1])
funcs[probability](data_struct, **arguments)

# ...

def func_1(data_s, arg_1, **kwargs):
    # blah blah blah

def func_2(data_s, arg_2, **kwargs):
    # blah blah blah

def func_3(data_s, arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    # blah blah blah
```

This works well enough, and I felt pretty smart when I finally got it all set up, but I'm changing the data_structure a bit, and now re-thinking both parts of this contraption:

- First, some of the arguments are random numbers, so instead of calling random.random() in all of the funcs, I'm calling it once in `build_arguments()`. Have I over thought this?
- And second, would it be smarter to set up an elaborate switch-style statement instead of the `**arguments` thing? Bisect into the index, grab the func name, and then if-then the correct function.

Example:

```
if name == 'func_1':
    func_1(data_struct, arg_1)
elif name == 'func_2':
    func_2(data_struct, arg_2)
elif name == 'func_3':
    func_3(data_struct, arg_1, arg_2)
# etc etc
```

- Third, and a little beside the point, all of these functions operate directly on the data within the structure, instead of being pure. Would it be smarter to pass in just the elements that will be modified instead of the entire data_structure?

Example:

```
func_3(data_struct, arg_1, arg_2)

# ...

def func_3(data_s, arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    alist = data_s.alist
    temp = alist[:arg_1] + alist[arg_2:]
    point = random.randint(len(temp))
    data_s.alist[:] = temp[:point] + alist[arg_1:arg_2] + temp[point:]
```

versus

```
data_s[:] = func_3(data_struct.alist, arg_1, arg_2)

# ...

def func_3(alist, arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    temp = alist[:arg_1] + alist[arg_2:]
    point = random.randint(len(temp))
    return temp[:point] + alist[arg_1:arg_2] + temp[point:]
```

Thanks so much!

---

Edit: Seems there's some confusion. I fixed a small error, but otherwise this works as described in both 3.4 and 3.5, as shown [in this gist I just created](https://gist.github.com/NoahTheDuke/6e8c88275c5e743fba971549d8b70759).

Comment: Did you actually try running any of this? `**arguments` does not allow passing any number of arguments to the function. It allows passing keyword arguments only. You want `*arguments` (one star). `*arguments` (or, more commonly, `*args`) is quite elegant, actually.

Comment: I just posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/NoahTheDuke/6e8c88275c5e743fba971549d8b70759) showing how this works. Double-star (`**args`) takes a dictionary and tries to fit the entries to the function's arguments, tossing the rest into `**kwargs` if they don't fit.

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation of your question is correct, you may want to build on this.

My interpretation is that you want to run one of many functions with the right number of arguments with the function chosen randomly and arguments generated randomly.

You'll have to change the selection of function to match your probability model obviously.

```
import inspect
import random

def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

def func3():
    pass

functions = [
  func1, func2, func3
]

random_func = random.choice(functions)
random_args = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(len(inspect.getfullargspec(random_func).args))]
random_func(*random_args)
```